# "1 times" is incorrect, every time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Recipients of newly-created badges live with the following reality:

[image]

Is it possible to have this print as

> **This badge has been awarded 1 time. Recently awarded to:**

in the event of a single instance?

Comment: This is a truncation error. If it was 1.0 times it would be grammatical. :)

Comment: Since you speak about it, I vote for "once".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pluralizations is hard, and fix are tricky; this has been discussed [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36888/23354) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20683/23354) [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9662/23354). Intriguingly, there may be some better options for this coming up in the medim-term future, depending on how some internal changes pan out. But at the current time this is by-design.

Comment: I'm looking forward to an update on this...

Comment: @Werner: look at  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/98364 for an example of the issue: if you want internationalisation, plurals don't correspond in different languages cleanly.